# How do I get Eclipse (with PyDev) to stop opening parallel versions of files?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I managed to get my Eclipse/PyDev environment set up pretty well: I can CTRL+click (or F3) a variable/function in the code editor, and have Eclipse take me to the definition of that reference.  That's great, but there's a problem.

I guess I must have done something wrong in my setup, because if I have file A open, and I CTRL+click/F3 a reference in file B that points to A, Eclipse doesn't bring up the (already open) tab for A; it opens up a new tab ... also of A.

(And then of course when I fail to notice what happened and wind up making some edits in one window, it causes Eclipse to get upset about the other window because it's now out of date.)

Does anyone know how I could have mis-configured Eclipse/PyDev to make this happen ... and more importantly, how I can fix it?

P.S. I'm using virtualenv to wrap my whole instance (should have mentioned that before, as it's probably relevant).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like PyDev is resolving some file externally (as if it was configured under an external source folder or under the python interpreter).

Is this a public project so that I can take a look at it (say on github?). Also, that happens always or just on some specific use cases?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I created a new PyDev project, then created a new folder with a link to my source dir (right-click on project, New - Folder - Advanced - link to alternate location). Now when I debug it opens a new external copy of the files that I'm stepping through. These have the full path in the title bar instead of <project name>/path/to/my/file .

Comment: If you have a reproducible use-case, please add step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce it at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: I have created ticket 456.